# How can I install customized Android OS?

Tags: custom-roms

I want to install customized Android OS in my *Samsung Galaxy III*.

Can we do that or not ?

If we can not do with *Galaxy III*, then is there any other phone on which we can do the same?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I want to customize android OS for specific requirement . For that I need to install that OS instead of the default OS provided with the Galaxy III by Samsung. Is it possible ?

Comment: customized OS means I am going to do code change in android source code and wanted to install that in a mobile again.

Comment: Are you talking about the galaxy 3 or the galaxy s3?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can, but you need to use a compatible ROM (if you don't want to break your phone). But before flashing it's recommended to read forums, where potential and actual problems with ROM are described.

   Example: [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1563) forums, Android Development subforums for you device (ROM are hardware specific).
2. Every phone with unlocked or possible to unlock bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own custom rom, e.g. customize the AOSP build, which is the most standard Android version you can imagine, no extra's from HTC or Samsung etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a custom launcher first? Nova and Apex (among others) give you a stock AOSP feel with many extras including the ability to use custom icon packs. You can get a customized look and feel without the warranty concerns that come with rooting and custom ROMs.